# Adding up check boxes, adding the price into a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database, checkbox

I'm trying to add tick boxes and when the boxes are ticked a value adds up (a variable) that variable is then added into the database along with each checkbox once the form is submitted, I've been trying to modifiy this code but cant figure out how to not use the parseInt() function and output a single variable that I can then add into the database/Email reply to the customer. I'm really stuck and would appreciate some help.

(the options are suppose to actually be (deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine but im using demo options for now below in the insert staement they are the correct names)
This is my HTML:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="option1" rel="11">furniture</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="extras[]"" value="option2" rel="12">tabs</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="option3" rel="13">urine</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="option4" rel="30">couch</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="option5" rel="20">steam</p>
<span id="output"></span>
```

This is my javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });
});
```

This is my email reply/datbase inserting at the moment

```
$idextra=$_POST['extras'];
$arr_num=count($idextra);
$i=0;
while ($i < $arr_num)
{

    $q="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (dateCreated, name, email, phone, comments,status,eventID, qty,dropoff,deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine) VALUES (NOW(),'".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$comments."','2','".$eventID."','".$qty."','".$dropoff."','{$idextra[1]}','{$idextra[2]}','{$idextra[3]}','{$idextra[4]}','{$idextra[5]}','{$idextra[6]}')";

    $res=mysql_query($qu) or die('ERROR INSERTING: '.mysql_error());
    $i++;
}
```

Thanks heaps for any advice/help in coding this. I know its a big question but I feel it will help a lot of people in the future.

Comment: for a start, delete the " on line two name attr name="extras[]""

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Calculating the sum for insertion in the database?

Comment: My variable for the price, i cannto figure out how to integrate it into the database as i have got the code from somewhere online

Answer (score 0):

```
$res=mysql_query($qu)
```

change that to

```
$res=mysql_query($q)
```

and probably this too

`name="extras[]""` to `name="extras[]"`

and i think array starts with 0, and the query would be:

```
while ($i < $arr_num){

    $q  = "INSERT INTO bs_reservations"; 
    $q .= " (dateCreated, name, email, phone, comments,status,eventID, qty,dropoff,deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine)";
    $q .= " VALUES (NOW(),'".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$comments."','2','".$eventID."','".$qty."','".$dropoff;
    $q .= "','".$idextra[0]."','".$idextra[1]."','".$idextra[2]."','".$idextra[3]."','".$idextra[4]."','".$idextra[5]."')";

    $res=mysql_query($q) or die('ERROR INSERTING: '.mysql_error());
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: in regards to the price variable how would i insert it into a database

Comment: price ? what price ? i didnt see any price on the fields ??

Comment: This java code calculates the price 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;
        var base = 100;
        
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
             sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel")) + base;
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });
});

Comment: yes i know that the js is calculating a price, but i cant see any "price" related field on the bs_reservations table. and since it is a client side script, the intention is probably to generate a price to be displayed on the client side.